# Image Size Doubling

Tags: android, image, bitmap, drawable

This might be a quick answer but I must not know what to search for as I can't find anyone talking about it! I have some png files in my drawables folder that are 88x88 pixels. I run my app and have a log print out the size of the images and it claims they are 176x176. What gives? Is something expanding my images before they go into the apk or is my phone really only half the resolution it claims?

Comment: Are they just in the `drawable` folder? Or in `drawable-mdpi`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BitmapFactory.decodeResource` scales images in the `Drawable` folder according to the DPI of the device (it generates a higher resolution image for high resolution screens).

If you don't want the image to be scaled on decoding, place it in the folder `Drawable-nodpi`

Comment: nodpi was just what I needed since I scale the images myself. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) guide:

"By default, Android scales your bitmap drawables (.png, .jpg, and .gif files) and Nine-Patch drawables (.9.png files) so that they render at the appropriate physical size on each device. For example, if your application provides bitmap drawables only for the baseline, medium screen density (mdpi), then the system scales them up when on a high-density screen, and scales them down when on a low-density screen. This scaling can cause artifacts in the bitmaps. To ensure your bitmaps look their best, you should include alternative versions at different resolutions for different screen densities."

So yes, your screen is probably xhdpi with density 2, so size of your image from unspecified drawables folder would be x2.

Comment: I did not realize these folders would scale my images. Thanks!